# Find all clients connect to socket in Flask-SocketIO

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

end in Flask and want to develop a chat service application with Flask-Socket.IO at this time , want to know all clients connected to Server. how do I do this?

Server Side:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins="*")
rooms = list()
@socketio.on('Register')
def handle_message(username):
    print(str(username) + ' Registered just now! : New User :))')
    rooms.append(username)
    join_room(username)
    emit('Register',"Success",room=username)
    clientIp = request.connection.remoteAddress
    user = Users_database(username=username, ip=clientIp, online_status=True)
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket io server have four events.

1. **connect**: when client connect to server will be trigger;
2. **disconnect**: when client disconnect to server will be trigger;
3. **message**: when client use send() function to send string data will be trigger;
4. **json**: when client use send() function to send json data will be trigger;

Maybe you can do it with thie code below here.

```py
@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    dosomething()

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    dosomething()
```

Comment: Thanks , do you know how could I know who was disconnected?

Comment: Similarly, you only need to listen the disconnect event in your server program.